# Update a Rails 3 partial using AJAX (not a form)

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I found a number of questions and answers regarding updating a partial using Ajax after submitting a form. But my question is ?simpler?, I just want to reload a partial every few seconds and load in the new data. This really can't be hard at all, and I remember doing something similar in Rails 2.3 but I can't find the answer anywhere.

Basically, I have a show.html.erb rendering a partial like so:

```
<div id="latest_post">
    <%= render :partial=>'info/latest', :object=>@user, :as=>:user %>
</div>
```

The partial file located at app/views/info/_latest

```
<% post = user.posts.last %>
<h1>Last Post</h1>
<p><%= post.content %></p>
```

I just want the latest_post div to be updated every 30 seconds. Please help!

Comment: Quick Idea: What if you used jQuery instead, run a time at e very 30 seconds (setInterval ?), and just replace the content?

Comment: @BenjaminTan Thanks, I already knew about the setInterval and jQuery part, but was trying to understand what to call using jQuery's AJAx methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well it turns out the answer is a little complicated:

Step 1: Use Javascript's `setInterval` function along with jQuery's `$.get()` function to load a page, say `/users/1/posts/latest`.

```
setInterval(function(){
  $.get("/users/1/posts/latest.js", function(data){
    $("latest_post").html(data);
  },
  "html")
}, 30000);
```

Step 2: Create a `latest.js.erb` and put it in your `app/views/posts` folder.

Contents of `latest.js.erb`:

```
<%= render partial: 'posts/latest', object: @user.posts.last, as: :post %>
```

Step 3: Create the above partial with whatever you'd like (if you don't need a partial, you can just write the entire contents of the div in the `latest.js.erb` file.)

Step 4: Add a latest method to your `PostsController`, that defines `@user`, etc. for the `latest.js.erb` to use.

Step 5: Add `get '/latest'` to your `routes.rb`

Comment: Where did you put the `setInterval()` function? application.js? Or in the page your partial is displayed in?

Comment: Well there are some differing opinions on this I think, but I used content_for :head on the page the partial is displayed on to output the javascript I need for that page.

Comment: Hi! I also patterned my solution on a similar [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48520865/refreshing-a-rails-partial-on-a-set-time-interval-using-ajax-and-jquery/48521196?noredirect=1#comment84052148_48521196) that I am having and I am wondering if there is any way for the setInterval to be called when the user is just viewing the current page (which needs to be refreshed)? I noticed that the _refresh_ is always called regardless of what page you're in.