# Is it possible to refresh partial frequently using Ajax?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

In background, I want it to reload and shows the number how many unread messages are there.
I want that without refreshing page.  I mean using ajax.

If I had this in menu, how can I refresh only this section every 30 secs?

```
<li><%= link_to sanitize('<i class="icon-envelope"></i> ') + "received messages" + sanitize(' <span class="badge badge-info">'+current_user.mailbox.inbox(:read => false).count(:id, :distinct => true).to_s+'</span>'), messages_received_path  %></li>
```

messages_controller.rb

```
  def received
    if params[:search]
     @messages = current_user.mailbox.inbox.search_messages(@search).page(params[:page]).per(10)
    else
     @messages = current_user.mailbox.inbox.page(params[:page]).per(10)
    end 
     add_crumb 'Messages Received', messages_received_path

     @box = 'inbox'
     render :index
  end
```

UPDATE:***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_***

assets/javascript/refresh_messages_count.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // will call refreshPartial every 3 seconds
    setInterval(refreshPartial, 3000)

});

function refreshPartial() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "messages/refresh_part";
 })
}
```

messages_controller.rb

```
def refresh_part
    @message_count = current_user.mailbox.inbox(:read => false).count(:id, :distinct => true)

    # get whatever data you need to a variable named @data 
    respond_to do |format| 
        format.js {render :action=>"refresh_part.js"} 
    end

end
```

views/layouts/_menu.html.erb

```
<span id="message_received_count"><%= render :partial => "layouts/message_received_count" %></span>
```

views/layouts/_message_received_count.html.erb

```
<% if user_signed_in? && current_user.mailbox.inbox(:read => false).count(:id, :distinct => true) > 0 %>
 <li><%= link_to sanitize('<i class="icon-envelope"></i> ') + "Received" + sanitize(' <span class="badge badge-info">'+@message_count.to_s+'</span>'), messages_received_path  %></li>
<% else %>
 <li><%= link_to sanitize('<i class="icon-envelope"></i> ') + "Received", messages_received_path  %></li>
<% end %>
```

views/messages/refresh_part.js.erb

```
$('#message_received_count').html("#{escape_javascript(render 'layouts/messages_received_count', data: @message_count)}");
```

Comment: Look at this [question], I think it's what you need.[1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11588251/update-a-rails-3-partial-using-ajax-not-a-form

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You will use setInterval to send the ajax request:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // will call refreshPartial every 3 seconds
    setInterval(refreshPartial, 3000)

});

// calls action refreshing the partial
function refreshPartial() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "whatever_controller/refresh_part"
 })
}
```

Then you make an action in a controller like this:

```
def refresh_part
  # get whatever data you need to a variable named @data
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

then you will write a js file named `refresh_part.js.haml` (you could erb instead of haml).

refresh_part.js.haml would look like this:

```
$('#part_you_want_to_refresh').html("#{escape_javascript(render 'name_of_partial', data: @data)}");
```

make sure you set the correct routes in `routes.rb`.

Comment: Thanks where should I put the ajax request part to??? should I write that directly to my controller? or do I need to make new file or something???

Comment: the jquery part should be in a js file that you include in your view, while the action should be just in a controller.

Comment: Yeah, I know. But I'm wondering why did you separate the ajax request and refresh_part.js??? could you please give me an example where to place ajax request at?

Comment: the refresh_part.js.haml is a file that will be served by the server as a response to the ajax request, it will not be included in the js of the view.
Check this cast on Unobtrusive Javascript http://railscasts.com/episodes/205-unobtrusive-javascript?view=asciicast, and this tutorial http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/using-unobtrusive-javascript-and-ajax-with-rails-3/

Comment: ahhh I got it what you meant! So I have to put the first block of your javascript in the head of layouts/application.html.erb? right?? If so, should I create file separated and render that file in application.html.erb?

Comment: I mean making js file in assets/javascripts

Comment: Thanks for response. I'm trying it right now.  url: "whatever_controller/refresh_part"; in ajax request should be something like  "messages/_received_count.html.erb"  ??

Comment: I updated my question.  I just followed your instruction and tried that codes but now it won't show anything now. and it seems not loading properly. Do you see any problem in my codes?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21526/discussion-between-khaled-and-husten)

Comment: nice step-by-step answer, however the semicolon after the url: "string" is incorrect, causes an "unexpected token ; error in javascript console

Comment: Would you please explain how to set the correct paths inside routes.rb? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

FYI, refresh_part.js.erb would look like this:

```
$("#part").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'partial', data: @data) %>");
```

instead of:

```
$('#part').html("#{escape_javascript(render 'partial', data: @data)}");
```

also, we can use the alias of "escape_javascript" to simplify this:

```
$("#part").html("<%= j(render 'partial', data: @data) %>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/JavaScript">
<!--
function timedRefresh(timeoutPeriod) {
    setTimeout("location.reload(true);",timeoutPeriod);
}
//   -->
</script>
</head>
<body onload="JavaScript:timedRefresh(5000);">
<p>This page will refresh every 5 seconds. This is because we're using the 'onload' event to call our function. We are passing in the value '5000', which equals 5 seconds.</p>
<p>But hey, try not to annoy your users too much with unnecessary page refreshes every few seconds!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Source: http://www.quackit.com/javascript/javascript_refresh_page.cfm

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. But I want to do it using rails and, apply just partial:)