# AJAX to fetch model data from view

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I get `[object Object]` when printing the results of my AJAX calls. Please help me find which part I'm not doing right.

The Event model has columns `name`, `description`. Am I correct to expect this kind of output?

```
{ "1" =>
  {
    "name" => "some name",
    "description" => "some description"
  }
}
```

> ### View:
>
> ```
> function testAJAX() {
>   var test_url = "#{foo_events_path}";
>   $.ajax({
>     type: "GET",
>     url: test_url,
>     data: {
>       event_id: 1
>     },
>     success:function(data) {
>       var response = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
>       alert(response.events);
>     }
>   });
> ```
>
> ### events_controller.rb
>
> ```
> def foo
>   @events = Event.where(id: params[:event_id])
>   render json: { events: @events }.to_json
> end
> ```
>
> ### routes.rb
>
> ```
> resources :events do
>   collection do
>     get 'foo'
>   end
> end
> ```

I tried googling but most of them uses AJAX for php. This is the closest I could find related to my question: [Is it possible to refresh partial frequently using Ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13988556/is-it-possible-to-refresh-partial-frequently-using-ajax)

Comment: I just realized, maybe the title should be "AJAX to fetch database records from view". my bad

Comment: Why are you doing `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))`? You may be receiving an array of json objects as a string, in which case just do the `JSON.parse(data)` bit. You can always do `console.log(typeof(data))` to see what type of data you are getting.

Comment: @jvillian okay so I removed the JSON.stringify() part then logged to the console. Now it says I have an error `JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data` so I'm guessing this means I have bad syntax in the controller method?

Comment: Remove the `to_json`, what do you get?

Comment: Well, actually, you're returning a hash, so you shouldn't have to do anything because a hash should be converted into a proper js object. And, yes, I'm guessing your `to_json` is incorrect. (Oh, I missed @SebastianPalma commenting. You may now safely ignore me.)

Comment: @SebastianPalma still the same error `JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data`

Comment: Remove `to_json` *and* don't do `JSON.parse`. See if your `data` object is valid.

Comment: @jvillian after removing `to_json` and using only this in the ajax call: `success:function(data) { var response = data; console.log(typeof(response))}`, the console output is `object`. Am I using the `data` right here?

Comment: Yeah, that should be a valid object. You should do `console.log(response)` to see what you have. BTW, seems extraneous to assign `data` to the `response` variable.

Comment: Okay now in the console I'm getting object with actual data inside. It's just a matter of accessing them properly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your controller method should look like:

```
def foo
  @events = Event.where(id: params[:event_id])
  render json: { events: @events }
end
```

The `render json:` will create a valid JSON response.

Then, you should be able access your data object like this:

```
function testAJAX() {
  var test_url = "#{foo_events_path}";
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: test_url,
    data: {
      event_id: 1
    },
    success:function(data) {
      alert(data.events);
    }
  });
```