# Access updated data without re rendering the whole page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a `Person` model whose location is updated every few seconds from a mobile app and saved to the database. Now I want to access the updated information in the view without re rendering the whole page.

How do I do that?

I want to do something like this

```
setInterval(function(){
  // display updated data
}, 5000);
```

p.s.: I am using JavaScript only for the time interval, this is a Rails question.

Reloading the page after every few seconds works but totally kills what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to refresh partial frequently using Ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13988556/is-it-possible-to-refresh-partial-frequently-using-ajax)

Comment: A possible use for [ActionCable](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the data with an ajax request.  Assume the `div` you want to update has id `current-location` you can do...

```
setInterval(function() {    
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "/people/<%=@person.id%>/get_location",
    success: function(data) {
      $('#current-location').html(data.location);
    }
  });
}, 5000);
```

In your routes.rb define a member path

```
resources :people 
  member do
    post :get_location
  end
end
```

Then create an action in your PeopleController called `get_location` and ensure the last lines are something like...

```
person_location = get_location # some method that returns location
render json: {location: person_location}
```

Comment: i did exactly as you said nothing happened

Comment: So if you look at the browser console are there any errors?

Comment: i have an empty div with an id of **current-location**, i have specified the routes files as you said and i have an action as follows in people_controller 
`person_location = current_user.people.last.latitude`
`render json: {location: person_location}`

Comment: it works perfectly but after 3-4 seconds i get this error in console 
**POST https://.../people/105/get_location net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES**

Comment: There were a few mismatched brackets that were causing the error

Comment: Ah, great, glad you got it sorted!