# Refreshing a rails partial on a set time interval using AJAX and JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a page in my rails application that looks like: [image: this image]

Now, I have another AI application coded in python that processes a video (displayed on the left of a page of the rails app) and populates the database with the captured vehicles and their corresponding license plates (displayed beside the video in the rails app). Meaning to say, the rails and python applications have a shared database.

What I want to do now is that I want to refresh the partial on the right, say every 10 seconds so that it will show the newly added vehicles. I patterned my current solution from this [stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11588251/update-a-rails-3-partial-using-ajax-not-a-form) and I was able to confirm that I can successfully render the js page as shown in my logs:

[image]

However, the partial still shows just one entry despite adding a new entry. I need to manually refresh the page for it to show all new entries. I am not sure where I made a mistake. Here are the following relevant codes that I have so far:

`application.js` 
//Responsible for the partial refresh

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  setInterval(refreshPartial, 1000);
});

function refreshPartial() {
  $.get("/single_live.js", function(data){
    $("#captured_vehicles_live").html(data);
  });  
}
```

`static_pages_controller.rb`

```
def single_live
  @all_captured_violators = CapturedViolatorPlaceholder.all.order('capture_date DESC')

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js
  end
end
```

`single_live.html.slim`

```
.ui.container style="margin-top: 100px;"
  .ui.container
    h1.ui.center.aligned.header Camera 1
    .ui.divider  
    .ui.left.aligned.grid.stackable
      .ten.wide.column
        .ui.segment
          image[src="http://62.242.189.219:80/mjpg/video.mjpg?COUNTER" style="border: 0 none transparent; min-height: 200px; max-height: 600px;" height="100%" width="100%" frameborder="0"]
      .six.wide.column 
        .ui.segment
          h1.ui.center.aligned.header
            | Captured License Plates
        = render 'captured_vehicles_live'
```

`single_live.js.slim`

```
= render partial: 'captured_vehicles_live', data: @all_captured_violators
```

`_captured_vehicles_live.html.slim` \partial

```
#captured_vehicles_live.ui.segment style="height: 450px; margin-top: 15px; overflow:scroll;"
  .ui.grid.stackable
    - @all_captured_violators.each do |violator|
      .row.ui.basic.segment
        .six.wide.column
          = image_tag "/MASTER/IMAGES/#{violator.car_image_filename}", style: "width: 100%; height: 100%;"
        .ten.wide.column
          = form_tag encode_license_plate_path do
            .row
              .ui.form
                .two.fields
                  .field
                    = image_tag("/MASTER/PLATES/#{violator.license_plate_image_filename}")
                  .field
                    = text_field_tag 'captured_violator[license_plate_text]', violator.license_plate_text
                    = hidden_field_tag 'captured_violator_placeholder[id]', violator.id
                    = hidden_field_tag 'violation[name]', violator.violation
                    = hidden_field_tag 'offense[location]', violator.location
                    = hidden_field_tag 'offense[car_image_filename]', violator.car_image_filename
                    = hidden_field_tag 'offense[license_plate_image_filename]', violator.license_plate_image_filename
              .row.center.aligned
                  = submit_tag "Encode", class: 'fluid ui button primary'
      .ui.divider
```

`routes.rb`

```
get '/single_live' => 'static_pages#single_live'
```

[WORKING UPDATE]

After trying to apply the recommendations below of @Matias Seguel, I now have this code:

`single_live_js.slim`

```
| $("#captured_vehicles_live").html("
= j render 'captured_vehicles_live'
| ");
```

I also removed the `$("#captured_vehicles_live").html(data);` from my `application.js` to avoid rendering my code twice.

`application.js`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  setInterval(refreshPartial, 1000);
});

function refreshPartial() {
  $.get("/single_live.js", function(data){});  
}
```

Comment: Your code looks fine. Have you tried insetting a debugger tool ([ByeBug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug) for example) to see if you receive more data in `def single_life`?

Comment: Oh yes I did try putting a [ByeBug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug) in my `def single_live` action and the parameters that I get is this: `<ActionController::Parameters {"controller"=>"static_pages", "action"=>"single_live", "format"=>"js"} permitted: false>`

Comment: But what is the value for your `@all_captured_violators`?

Comment: Hi @PeterHøjlundAndersen! It's working now after receiving help from @Matias ' thread below. I really appreciate your help! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try doing something like:

*single_live.js.slim*

```
$("#captured_vehicles_live").html("<%= j render 'captured_vehicles_live' %>");
```

or if you are using slim:

```
| $("#captured_vehicles_live").html("
= j render 'captured_vehicles_live'
| ");
```

There is no need to pass @all_captured_violators again.

Do not forget to also remove `$("#captured_vehicles_live").html(data);` in the `application.js` so it would finally look like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  setInterval(refreshPartial, 1000);
});

function refreshPartial() {
  $.get("/single_live.js", function(data){});  
}
```

Comment: Hi @Matias! I tried but it produces this error:

`ActionView::Template::Error (Unknown line indicator
  /home/cjay-ipttu/Documents/Git/aicatch/app/views/static_pages/single_live.js.slim, Line 1, Column 0
    $("#captured_vehicles_live").html("<%= j render 'captured_vehicles_live' %>");
    ^
):
    1: $("#captured_vehicles_live").html("<%= j render 'captured_vehicles_live' %>");`

Comment: Oh, i just googled it and seems to be a slim issue. I don't know what to do with that :(

Comment: Maybe it will be useful 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27158328/rewrite-template-js-erb-into-template-js-slim

Comment: The [gem](https://github.com/slim-template/slim/wiki/Template-Converters-ERB-to-SLIM) was certainly useful! I can determine now that the partial is getting updated when new entry is inserted. I encountered another problem with how it being shown in the html. Will update my question! Thank you so much for your help so far @Matias!

Comment: Updated the question with new accompanying screenshots for the unexpected behavior!

Comment: Glad to be helpful. 

Did you remove the $("#captured_vehicles_live").html(data); in $.get request? , maybe your code is rendered twice

Comment: That's exactly it! I think it is now working exactly how I want it to be. I really owe you one @Matias! I might encounter more problems as I build the app so I'd probably post more often (though I hope that there would be existing similar problems already lol). See you around!

Comment: @Whooper Unfortunately your suggested edit was rejected due to the fact that users in that queue do not necessarily know if what you added was correct or not. You can ask Matias to override the rejection, if he feels like it is warranted for inclusion in his answer.

Comment: @FrankerZ sure no worries!